# Reading and writing files within Jar

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jar

I have finally completed a program in Java and I have to upload it.
The problem is that I have to upload also the executable .jar file and not only the eclipse project.

The main functionality of my program consists by reading and writing .xml files (for example one file is used to read and add new users), and the files in the project folder are so located:

-Project Name

- src

  - default package

    - main and all other classes
- file1.xml
- file2.xml

So the two .xml files are in the root of the project.

My question is: It is better to save the .xml files in the JAR and then writing and reading them from the executable program or it is better to store them in a folder outside the .JAR and reading and writing them as externally files?

It is a good practice to create a folder like that?:

-ProjectName

- file1.xml
- file2.xml
- project.jar

I read in Stackoverflow a lot of people having my same issue and a lot of people doesnt know how to manage this problem properly.

Thank you in advance for the reply :)

Comment: This really depends if you ever want to modify those files. What are the XML files?

Comment: Yes I want to modify them, for example one file is used to add new users.

Comment: its best to keep, any files you want to read run-time outside the "jar", as there may be a case, you might be changing the file later and scratching your head that why isn't reflecting in the program

Comment: I might use a SQLite database for "adding users" or any other data that you may search over or update frequently, but sure, keep the files outside the JAR because I don't believe changes can't be made to it at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may read a XML file located inside the executable Jar but it is not possible to update (write) a XML file located inside that executable Jar file. So the best option would be:-

```
-ProjectName    
    file1.xml
    file2.xml
    project.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing files in JAR-files can have all sorts of problems. That starts with simple things such as what should happen when you want to update your program to the newest version? Usually you'd just swap the jar, but then you loose everything you edited so far. You'd need a process to update inside the jar.

Other problems include that for changing the jar file you need to open it, possibly realign contents and rewrite the index which could conflict with the JVM that is reading the jar at the same time causing odd behaviour. On some systems (windows...) the Jar file might even be locked while the application is running and thus you cannot write to it at all.

I'd suggest that you add "default files" (in case that your files are initially not just empty) to you Jar file that represent the initial state. If the application is started you check if the XML files exist in the some normal writable directory and if they don't just copy the default files to that directory. This allows you to deploy still just a single jar file, but once started the appropriate files will be created.

Answer (score 1):

The jar should be kept read-only, the XML "files" inside the jar should be read using `getResource[AsStream]` (class path). You can use those *resources* as templates to create a copy in the user's (or application's) directory/sub-directory. For the user's directory:

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```